# AWK/SED Remove a specific latex command from the text AND closing bracket behind it

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

How to remove a specific latex command from the text AND closing bracket behind it, but to keep the text inside the brackets/

Please fill free to suggest SED, or AWK, or Perl or whatever will do the job

Input sensless example:

```
We \edit{Introduce a} model for analyzing \emph{data} from various
experimental designs, \edit{such as 23 paired or longitudinal}.
```

Output:

```
We Introduce a model for analyzing \emph{data} from various 
experimental designs, such as 23 paired or longitudinal.
```

PS. I am introducing a lot of small edits into my tex file. I want those edits to be highlighted, so my collaborator can see them. But afterwards I would like to remove all highlights with one or two commands.

Comment: you can do it with sed if you know about things like meta characters, character classes and capture groups... or perhaps there is a latex aware cli tool... do try to solve it yourself before asking..

Comment: ... sorry, but your input always changes... a reliable sample would be appreciate.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Now the example is representative.

Comment: It appeared that my example was again too soft . Here is more realistic one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373772/remove-a-specific-latex-command-from-the-text-and-closing-bracket-behind-it

Comment: See ilkkachu answer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373772/remove-a-specific-latex-command-from-the-text-and-closing-bracket-behind-it

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
We \edit{introduce a} model for analyzing data from various
experimental designs, \edit{such as paired or longitudinal}.

$ sed 's/\(\\edit{\)\([a-z ]*\)\(}\)/\2/g' file
We introduce a model for analyzing data from various
experimental designs, such as paired or longitudinal.
```

If your file look like this:

```
$ cat file
We \edit{Introduce a} model for analyzing \emph{data} from various
experimental designs, \edit{such as 23 paired or longitudinal}.
```

Then you should try:

```
sed 's/\(\\[a-z]*{\)\([A-Za-z0-9 ]*\)\(}\)/\2/g' file
We Introduce a model for analyzing data from various
experimental designs, such as 23 paired or longitudinal.
```

If you want to keep `\emph{data}` then use:

```
$ sed 's/\(\\edit{\)\([A-Za-z0-9 ]*\)\(}\)/\2/g' file
We Introduce a model for analyzing \emph{data} from various
experimental designs, such as 23 paired or longitudinal.
```

Or a more smooth way:

```
$ sed 's/\\edit{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g' file
```

Comment: `sed 's/\(\\edit{\)\([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*\)\(}\)/\2/g' file` Thank you. I've made too narrow example

Comment: ... sorry, but the input example always changes...

Comment: My fault. Your solution works perfect (apart from technical trivial issue with digits, which where not in the initial example).  Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: `\edit` Should stay in the second case as well. But I've got the idea. Thank you very much indeed

Comment: @JohnGoofy instead of aiming to match valid characters between {}, you can simply match other than }... for ex: `sed 's/\\edit{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g'`

Comment: @Sundeep Yes, this is very smooth, indeed.

Comment: @Sundeep It appeared my example was again too narrow. But your solution works for real file, where might be citations inside \edit{}